# Junit Testing with data file

Tags: java, json, testing, junit, automated-tests

Sorry I the question is duplicated, if its the case, please link the thread.

I want to test Java with Junit. Now I have a data file and read out these datas. How could I validate them? I tried it with class and objects but if I have a lot of test cases, there would be a lot of classes which is uncomfortable to test. My goal is to trigger different actions in java depending on the data's I have read in.

To get my point, here is my example data file:

```
{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
}
```

We assume that we have read out these key/value pairs.

If I want to continue working with these values, **HOW** can I validate them? Like how is it possible to check if the key fruit and the value apple is spelled correctly? 
It could be that I have an alphabet wrench in the inside or something like that.

I hope you can give me other options than making an object an working with them.

Comment: JUnit is for validating how your code works, not for validating data in a file.

Comment: yeah I know. But if I have a unvalide data outta a file then my code might be not working. And if its still not working, then it is my code/logic

Comment: I will reiterate: JUnit test is for the code, not the file. In test, you always assume your file is correct, and you simply test what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

When you read the file in, I'm assuming that you are storing the key, value pairs into a data structure that implements the `Map` interface?

I am also making the assumption that you have a discrete set of inputs that are legal. E.g, `"Apple", "Orange", "Pear"` for the `"fruit"` attribute.

In which case these valid inputs could be stored in a `Set`. You could then use this set for checking validation. If the input in the data file for `"fruit"` is `"Apple"` then check that the validation set contains the String `"Apple`. If it does then the input is valid, if not then you can throw an exception.

Once this is implemented, a unit test will be able to test that your code is acting appropriately for the given inputs. You can use Junit to test that the relevant exception is being thrown with invalid inputs.

Hopefully this helps. It's likely not the cleverest or most efficient way of doing things but should get you to where you want to be.

Comment: Yes exactly, it implements a Map. Thank you! I'll try